# Issues with OnClick Listener for Custom Dialog Box

Tags: android

I am trying to write a custom dialog box that takes a name from the user. I am getting a "OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})" error in Eclipse. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here is my Code:

```
public void getName(){

         Dialog dialog = new Dialog(main.this);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
         dialog.setTitle("New Game");
         dialog.setCancelable(true);
         //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!
         final EditText inputBox = new EditText(this);

         //set up text
         final TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
         text.setText("Enter Your Name...");


         //set up button
         final Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.namebutton);
         button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick() {
             String str = inputBox.getText().toString(); 
             setName(str);
             }
         });
         //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
         dialog.show();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are importing the wrong `OnClickListener`. Make sure you have:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

instead of

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

Answer (score 3):

You may just need to change this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

to this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

EDIT - To kind of combo our answers, also make sure that you're importing the correct class as Cristian has stated.